# Nginx redirect 404 for a sub-url yii framework

Tags: php, redirect, yii, nginx, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to redirect 404 pages to my main site with the following config in nginx :

```
server {

    listen   80; 

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/mysite;

    include /etc/nginx/rewrite/*.conf;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
            index index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^/(news|items)/? {
            error_page      404     =301 @redirect;
    }

    location @redirect {
            rewrite .* / permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.socket;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

As with this config, all 404 pages are redirected to / site.

How can I further tweak this config so that I will just redirect ONLY 404 that occurs on a sub-url and their down line with a 301 (eg. /news/***/*** and /items/***) while keep the other 404 intact?

To illustrate further :
To redirect 404 for the following with 301 :

```
/news/
/items/
```

To keep 404 for the rest, for example :

```
/
/posts
/images
/videos
```

UPDATE : I've modified the config based on recommendation by Melvin. It now redirects everything requests that starts with /news and /items regardless of whether is 404 or not. I'm using Yii PHP Framework. There are no physical location for the folders mentioned above, they are just a route for Yii.

UPDATE 2 : Found a solution. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this. Not sure whether it is a good practise or not but certainly worth a try if you are using PHP framework that does internal redirection.

I've added an 'if' statement that checks for $request_uri variable for the ones that I want to have custom 404

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.socket;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/(news|items) {
            error_page      404     =301 @redirect;
        }
}
```

Of course the following block was removed

```
location ~ ^/(news|items)/? {
        error_page      404     =301 @redirect;
}
```

This way, I can have all 404s under /news/ and /items/ redirected while the others are being handled by PHP default error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you set the error page on the server level, but error_page also works within a location.

So for any location you want to override the default behavior, just add a location and resupply the error_page.

Don't be afraid to repeat yourself, with nginx is preferred over complex regular expressions.

In your case you want the default behavior to be different, so just remove that error_page from the server level and only set it on /news/ and /items/.

Finally, since the destination is static you can just use:

```
error_page 404 =301 $scheme://$host/;
```

Comment: I have removed the server-wide error page and added a location        location ~ ^/(news|items)/? {
            error_page      404     =301 @redirect;
    }. It now seems to redirect everything regardless of whether it is 404 or not.